# What are the exact words of Kalimat ash-Shahadah?

Tags: shahada

Is it

> لا إله إلا الله محمدا رسول الله

which translates into

> There is no god but Allah and Muhammad is his messenger

?

Or is it

> أشهد أن لا إله إلا الله محمدا رسول الله

which translates into

> I bear witness that there is no god but Allah and Muhammad is his messenger

?

Are these two formally inter-changeable? Which one is said to enter Islam? Can both be used?

Comment: Another variant can be *Ašhadu an lā ilāha illā-llāh waḥdahu lā šarīka lahu, wa ašhadu anna muḥammadan ʿabduhu wa rasūluhu.* (I bear witness that (there is) no god except Allah; One is He, no partner hath He, and I bear witness that Muhammad is His Servant and Messenger.) ([Source - #2 in this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Kalimas)). I reckon they're same.

Answer (score -7):

The second phrase is true. and you can not inter change them. And for entering Islam you to say the second phrase.

Because all people (even Christians and Jews) know there is no God but Allah and Muhammad(PBUH) is his messenger. but for being a Muslim you have to bear witness that there is no God but Allah,

And Please mention that for  SHAHADAH you have to say it in Arabic and without any mistake.

Comment: I want to know why my answer has got down voted.

Comment: *all people (even Christians and Jews) know there is no God but Allah and Muhammad(PBUH) is his messenger* is incorrect.

Comment: As you know all Jews and Christians know it. The news of coming last messenger had come in their books. All the history before and after of the prophet birth shows that the people of these two religion had been waited for the last messenger. So all the scholars of these two religion know this.

Comment: @Fatemeh What you are claiming is as good as a conspiracy theory. I'm afraid I'll have to downvote your answer as well.